# changing button style with another button

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to change a CSS button's style and/or text based on clicking another button? Let me give you a simplified example:

Say at the top of the page there are a series of buttons asking you to pick a category. You click on one of three buttons.

Other buttons on the page should change depending on which category button was clicked. For example, if you clicked Category A button, button 2 might be green and say "click for something", while if you picked Category B, it would be red and say "don't click this". (It wouldn't be disabled, just marked. I want to discourage clicking, not prohibit it.) Also, the buttons would need to have a default in case someone wants to click them without picking a category.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I apologize for not including code, but I wasn't sure even *if* it could be done. With the guidance of the first answerers, I have made an attempt, but it still doesn't work.

```
<style>
table, th, td {border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid; color: #FFFFFF}
th {background-color: black;}

.top {width:110px; height: 25px; background-color: #FFFF00; color: #000000;}
.off {width:110px; height: 25px; background-color: #DDDDDD; color: #000000;}

</style>


<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan=4>Click on favorite sport:</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><button class="top" onclick=document.getElementById("bb").style.background-color: #009900; color = #FFFFF;>BASEBALL</button></td>
    <td><button class="top" onclick=document.getElementById("fb").style.background-color: #0000DD; color = #FFFFFF;>FOOTBALL</button></td>
    <td><button class="top" onclick=document.getElementById("bk").style.background-color: #EE4500; color = #FFFFFF;>BASKETBALL</button></td>
    <td><button class="top" onclick=document.getElementById("bk").style.background-color: #89CFF0; color = #FFFFFF;>HOCKEY</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan=4>Click on favorite team:</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><button class="off" id="bb">YANKEES</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="fb">COWBOYS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="bk">CELTICS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="bk">CANADIENS</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button class="off" id="bb">CUBS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="fb">PACKERS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="bk">LAKERS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="bk">PENGUINS</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I *am* trying, but learning new coding at my age is tedious.

Here is an idea of what *should* happen:

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mi0f.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, but you need to narrow your request down to a single, clear goal, and show us that you have made some sort of attempt at it and let us know what specifically you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML use the onclick event to run a javascript function. In javascript use document.getElementById("elementIdHere").style.backgroundColor = "red"; to change the background color.
[See Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

and
 document.getElementById("elementIdHere").innerHTML = "Your text here";
 to change the text.
[See Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: I edited my original question to be more specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you can do it,
You can create a class in your css page and then add the class to your button using:

```
document.getElementById("change").setAttribute("class","button");
```

where "change" is your button's id that you want to change the style. see
[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/w1hwoqjg/2/)

or you can change the style using:

```
document.getElementById("change").style.color = "red";
```

**Edit**: base on your changes:
1) remember to define specific values for each element `id` attribute. if you want to change more than one element style, you can use it by element's `class` attribute.
2) you have to spell `background-color`in java script codes as `backgroundColor`.
3)It is better to define function in java script rather than define as an element attribute.

Your HTML codes:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan=4>Click on favorite sport:</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><button class="top" id="1" onclick="ChangeColor(this.id);">BASEBALL</button></td>
    <td><button class="top" id="2" onclick="ChangeColor(this.id);">FOOTBALL</button></td>
    <td><button class="top" id="3" onclick="ChangeColor(this.id);">BASKETBALL</button></td>
    <td><button class="top" id="4" onclick="ChangeColor(this.id);">HOCKEY</button></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan=4>Click on favorite team:</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><button class="off" id="a">YANKEES</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="b">COWBOYS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="c">CELTICS</button></td>
    <td><button class="b off" id="d">CANADIENS</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button class="b off" id="e">CUBS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="f">PACKERS</button></td>
    <td><button class="b off" id="g">LAKERS</button></td>
    <td><button class="off" id="h">PENGUINS</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Your CSS:

```
table, th, td {border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid; color: #FFFFFF}
th {background-color: black;}

.top {width:110px; height: 25px; background-color: #FFFF00; color: #000000;}
.off {width:110px; height: 25px; background-color: #DDDDDD; color: #000000;}
```

And your JS:

```
 function ChangeColor(flag){
  switch (flag) {
    case "1" : document.getElementById("a").style.color = "red";
               document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor  = "pink";
               breake;
    case "2" : $('.b').css('color', 'red');
               $('.b').css('background-color', 'pink');
               breake;
  }
}
```

could you please check : [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/b0gvfjv7/3/)

Comment: I edited my original question to be more specific. Thank you.

Comment: first of all, you have to give your elements, distinct "id" value.

Comment: I have updated my answer, would you please check it and the link inside it?

Comment: @MichaelRudolf, did you check the solution?

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it does not do what I am seeking. I guess it cannot be done. I will fiddle with it a while, but I am too frustrated and I may give up. Thanks again for a great effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript functions to change the class of the CSS buttons.

Ex. Create multiple classes for the buttons you are displaying. Set the default class of each button in the HTML. With the `onClick` event you call a JavaScript function that can change the class of any item in the HTML, allowing you to change the way it is displayed through all the CSS styling.